# Open kitchen cupboard on keypressed with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have recently downloaded a cabinet kitchen → https://www.cgtrader.com/3d-models/interior/kitchen/ca-5cd9388f-0be1-4cea-ab44-bc1b493f590f

So everything basically works fine, however, I've added a player controller and I want for each cupboard, that the player press `E` to open it. I'm having some serious difficulties with that though since every cupboard opens instead of only one and I don't know how to focus on only one at the time, maybe adding a box collider for when the player is close to a cupboard?

Plus, I've found two different types of keypressing :

→ `Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E)` = which slightly opens every cupboard but not entirely

→ `Input.GetKey("e")` = which fully opens every cupboard but you have to keep pressing `E` and this is not what I want.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Door : MonoBehaviour {

    public bool isopen;
    public float speed;

    [SerializeField]
    float Open,Close;


    private void Awake()
    {

    }
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (Input.GetKey("e"))
        {
            isopen = true;
            Quaternion open = Quaternion.Euler(Open, 90, 90);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, open, Time.deltaTime * speed);
        }

        else
        {
            isopen = false;
            Quaternion close = Quaternion.Euler(Close, 90, 90);
            transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.localRotation, close, Time.deltaTime * speed);

        }
    }


    void PlayAnim()
    {
        print("hit");

        if (isopen)
        {
            isopen = false;
        }

        else
        {
            isopen = true;
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my 'HIT' script :

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class hit : MonoBehaviour
{

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E))
        {
            RaycastHit hit;
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 100.0f))
            {

                hit.transform.SendMessage("PlayAnim");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the script works only for my drawers but not for my cupboard which are all slightly opened when E is pressed.
But when the player looks at a drawer, they press E and only the drawer they focused opens, same steps for closing it.
I've added the HIT script to my cupboards though...

So, I would like to be able to open a single cupboard when needed, and press `E` again to close it.
How am I supposed to do? Any directions?
Thank you very much guys.

Comment: I think your best course of action will be to break down the problem into its most general form. You want to be able to look at an object and interact with it somehow.

Comment: Yes, and I don't know to do that..

Comment: You need to know which one you are wanting to open. Do you want the one the user is looking at? Some reticle is pointing at? All objects get keyboard events, which is why they all open. You need to have some code in there to determine if the user is currently looking at (or pointing at) that cupboard.

Comment: In short, use a `Raycast` in the direction you are facing to determine which object you are facing. Then, apply your keypress to the selected object.

Comment: I want a text to appear when the player is close enough to a cupboard, the text says 'Press E to open', the player then press E, the cupboard opens and the text disappears, the play moves slightly and another text canvas pops saying 'Press E to close' and the cupboard closes. It is as simple as that and yet, I have no idea how to realize it. I've created a canvas which is written 'Press E to open' but I have no idea how to make it disappear when the event is triggered.

Comment: Making objects appear and disappear is done by using GameObject.SetActive(boolean)

Comment: This question just got a little confusing, you should try not to change a question in a way that invalidates the answers or could confuse future readers. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem would best be solved by breaking it into parts: Selecting a cupboard with a key, making it open/close and running the animation.

If you are using a first person view, you could check which cupboard the player is looking at by casting a ray using Physics.Raycast() from the position of the camera at the direction it is looking at. If the resulting RaycastHit collided with a cupboard, this one will need to open. By the way, GetKeyDown() fires once on a single Update() when the key is pressed, GetKey() fires as long as the key is held. You want to only fire once and keep the animation running by itself from then, so use GetKeyDown(). You would probably not want to use a box collider for that, as the player could open a cabinet behind him, just by rubbing his back against it and pressing "e".

Then, in a different script attached to the cupboards, you have to have a function to open/close them. As soon as it is called, you check whether it is currently moving, and if not, start the animation.

The animation will need to rotate the door on every frame in Update() until it reached the target position. By saving how far it moved already and whether it is closing or opening in variables, this should be rather easy to achieve because you already managed to make them rotate in the right way.

Comment: So I edited the script called 'Hit' using the Raycast thing, I have edited my main post for you to give a look and what problem it caused.

Answer (score 0):

It finally works! I have added the hit script and Physics.RayCast and edited the Door script. Now I have to figure out how to add the text canvas and makes it disappear when needed.
Thank you anyways!

Comment: This is not exactly an answer, but i'm glad it works. I would recommend using hit.transform.gameObject.GetComponent<Door>().PlayAnim() instead of SendMessage(). In addition, you should do the Raycast first in every Update and then check whether the key "E" was pressed. That way you can show/hide the text when the ray hits.

Comment: Sorry I am new to SOF, I'll take all you advice thank you very much.

Comment: Youre welcome, everybody here wants to help :) Try taking the tour, if you haven't done that already and feel free to read through the help center on how to ask questions or write answers: https://stackoverflow.com/tour